# How to move a unique_ptr from one set to another? (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, set, move, smart-pointers

The code below is giving the error: `Call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<int>' 'unique_ptr' has been explicitly marked deleted here passing argument to parameter 'item' here`.

Could someone please explain why this is? I would have thought everything would be fine because I'm using `std::move` in the call to `foo.add`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

class Foo {
 public:
  void add(std::unique_ptr<int> item) {
    set.emplace(std::move(item));
  }
 private:
  std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> set;
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;

  std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> set;
  set.emplace(std::make_unique<int>(1));
  set.emplace(std::make_unique<int>(2));
  set.emplace(std::make_unique<int>(3));

  for (auto &item : set) {
    foo.add(std::move(item)); // error on this line
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Elements in `std::set` are read-only. You are iterating over collection by const-iterator.

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix this? I thought I'd only be using const iterator if I specified `for (const auto & item : set) {...}`?

Comment: How about `Foo(std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> set) : set(std::move(set)) {}` and `Foo foo(std::move(set));` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [c++ 17 `extract()` function.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract)

[example](https://godbolt.org/z/TqG3vMEW9)

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto s = std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>>{};

    s.insert(std::make_unique<int>(10));

    std::cout << s.size() << "\n";

    auto it = s.extract(s.begin());

    // Pointer type here just for clarification
    std::unique_ptr<int> new_ptr = std::move(it.value());
    
    std::cout << s.size() << "\n";
    
    std::cout << *new_ptr << "\n";
}
```

Then instead of your for each loop you might use a while loop:

```cpp
while (!set.empty()) {
   auto it = set.extract(set.begin());
   foo.add(std::move(it.value());
}
```

Comment: @churill I do not se the problem there. Functions that is a "unique_ptr sink" should most often take the pointer by value. You just need to move it.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, my bad. For some reason I thought `unique_ptr`'s copy-ctor would be deleted, silly me.

Comment: Easy mistake. The curse of being a c++ programmer and having to memorize all different constructors and argument types :P